# Objetos mutables como argumentos por defecto en python

Tags: python

Tengo una duda con el paso de argumentos en `python`, cuando se pasan como argumentos estructuras de datos mutables, por ejemplo una `lista`, y otro argumento sencillo, de la siguiente forma:

```
def  arguments_mutables(arg, arg1=[]):
    """returns arguments mutables"""
    arg1.append("Arguments")


print(arguments_mutables(1))
print(arguments_mutables(2))
print(arguments_mutables(3))
```

Resulta que al pasar como argumento el valor para `arg` cada llamado se aumenta un `indice` para la `lista`, me pueden explicar porque se guarda el `índice` para cada llamada a la función.

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de cual es el resultado que esperas y cual es el resultado que estas obteniendo?

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta de Javier es muy buena pero solo resuelve tu caso específico, tal vez lo que quieres saber realmente es que las listas trabajan por **referencia**.

Lo que quiere decir esto es que si creas una lista `l1`:

```
>>> l1 = []
```

En realidad lo que estás haciendo es pasarle una referencia al objeto. Por lo tanto si luego creas otra lista en base a la primera:

```
>>> l2 = l1
```

Ahora `l2` tiene la referencia al mismo objeto. Para entenderlo mejor, considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l2.append(4)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l1 is l2 # Tienen referencia al mismo objeto
True
```

Como ves, al agregar un elemento a `l2` también ocurre lo mismo para `l1` ya que ambas variables tienen la referencia a la misma lista.

Ocurre lo mismo con los diccionarios:

```
>>> d1 = {'nombre': 'Cesar'}
>>> d2 = d1
>>> d2['apellido'] = 'Bustios'
>>> d1
{'apellido': 'Bustios', 'nombre': 'Cesar'}
>>> d2
{'apellido': 'Bustios', 'nombre': 'Cesar'}
>>> d1 is d2 # Tienen referencia al mismo objeto
True
```

Lo que sucede al ejecutar tu script, es que en la definición de tu función `arguments_mutables`, estás creando en `arg1` la **referencia** a una lista, es por eso que las llamadas sucesivas a esta función incrementan el tamaño de la lista ya que en realidad se está usando la referencia al mismo objeto.

Si quieres mantener el objeto original al aplicarle alguna operación, lo que tienes que hacer es pasarle una copia del objeto. En el caso de las listas esto es muy sencillo:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2 = l1[:] # Una copia, un objeto nuevo
>>> l2.extend([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> l1 is l2 # No tienen referencia al mismo objeto
False
```

En el caso de los diccionarios, puedes usar el método `copy`:

```
>>> d1 = {'nombre': 'Cesar'}
>>> d2 = d1.copy() # Una copia, un objeto nuevo
>>> d2['apellido'] = 'Bustios'
>>> d1
{'nombre': 'Cesar'}
>>> d2
{'apellido': 'Bustios', 'nombre': 'Cesar'}
>>> d1 is d2 # No tienen referencia al mismo objeto
False
```

Para diccionarios más complejos debes usar [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Si tienes una función, también puedes pasarle la copia para conservar el objeto original. Considera la siguiente función:

```
import random

def extendedora(lista):
    lista.append(random.randint(6, 10))
    return lista
```

Ahora, el primer caso, utilizando la misma lista:

```
>>> lista_original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lista_extendida = extendedora(lista_original)
>>> lista_original
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
>>> lista_extendida
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
>>> lista_original is lista_extendida
True
```

Utilizando una copia para mantener la lista original:

```
>>> lista_original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lista_extendida = extendedora(lista_original[:])
>>> lista_original
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lista_extendida
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> lista_original is lista_extendida
False
```

Answer (score 2):

> Los valores por defecto son evaluados de izquierda a derecha cuando la
> definición de la función se ejecuta. Esto significa que la expresión
> es evaluada una sola vez, cuando se define la función, y ese mismo
> valor "pre-computado" se usa para cada llamada. Esto es especialmente
> importante de comprender cuando un argumento por defecto es un objeto
> mutable, tal como una lista o un diccionario: si la función modifica
> el objeto (por ejemplo añadiendo un item a la lista), el valor por
> defecto en efecto es modificado. Esto generalmente no es la intención.
>
> [Function Definitions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

Por ejemplo, la siguiente función acumula los argumentos que se le pasan en llamadas sucesivas:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
  L.append(a)
  return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))

# Esto imprime
# [1]
# [1, 2]
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Si no quieres que el valor por defecto sea compartido entre llamadas sucesivas a la función puedes escribirla de esta forma:

```
def f(a, L=None):
  if L is None:
    L = []
  L.append(a)
  return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))

# Esto imprime
# [1]
# [2]
# [3]
```